# Best migration plugin in grails?

Tags: grails

I come to grails from rails.
I need a database migration tool similar to the rails migration.
I need to keep always updated the database (schema and data) for the webapp that i ship.
Any hint?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, the [autobase plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/autobase) is probably the best migration plugin for grails. It is based on the Liquibase plugin but makes it so you don't have to rely on xml configuration.

Comment: Just be aware that it's no longer supported by it's author. I use it, and it works but we do have couple of work arounds to get it to play nice with other plugins.

Comment: uhm not yet supported it's a good news

Comment: The plugin seems to supported again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually suggest either the liquibase plugin, or possibly just liquibase outside of grails.  The plugin itself isn't truthfully documented all that well (but it works great), but the liquibase framework itself is, and is easy to use.

Autobase is also based on liquibase under the covers, but as other have noted, it isn't supported anymore and I'm not sure that it was feature complete when Robert stopped working on it.